# Reason of additional destructor call?

Tags: c++, destructor

Given is the following simple class:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
    int a, b;
    public:
        Foo(int _a = 0, int _b = 0) : a(_a), b(_b) { 
            std::cout << "Foo(int, int)" << "\n"; 
        }

        Foo(const Foo& foo) : a(foo.a), b(foo.b) { 
            std::cout << "Foo(const Foo&)" << "\n"; 
        }

        Foo& operator=(const Foo& other) { 
            std::cout << "operator=(const Foo&)" << "\n"; 
            if(this != &other){
                a = other.a; 
                b = other.b;
            }
            return *this; 
        }

        ~Foo() { 
            std::cout << "~Foo()" << "\n"; 
        }

        Foo operator+(const Foo& other){
            std::cout << "foo.operator+(const Foo&)" << "\n";
            return Foo(a + other.a, b + other.b);
        }
};
```

and the main:

```cpp
int main(){
    Foo f1, f2(1, 2), f3;
    std::cout << "-----------" << "\n";
    f3 = f1 + f2;                          // (*)
    std::cout << "-----------" << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with `-std=c++11` and for demonstration purposes also with the `-fno-elide-constructors` flag. The output reads as:

```
Foo(int, int)
Foo(int, int)
Foo(int, int)
-----------
foo.operator+(const Foo&) // (1)
Foo(int, int)             // (2)
Foo(const Foo&)           // (3)
~Foo()                    // (4)
operator=(const Foo&)     // (5)
~Foo()                    // (6)
-----------
~Foo()
~Foo()
~Foo()
```

As far as I understand it correctly, the following happens for the line `f3 = f1 + f2;` (*):

1. Obviously, `f1.operator+(f2)` is called.
2. A new (temporary) object is created. Let's denote it by `T`.
3. Since the `operator+()` function does not return a reference, we call to copy constructor in order to construct a copy `T2` of `T`. We return `T2`.
4. The destructor is called in order to delete the temporary object `T`.
5. We call the copy assignment operator to assign all members of `T2` to `f3`.

My question: I don't really see what's the purpose of (6). Why is there an additional call to the destructor, i.e. what am I missing here?

Comment: It would help your debugging/understanding if you included the value of `this` in your output messages.  Then you will see which operations are invoked on which object instances

Comment: The temporary `T2` also needs to be destructed. That's (6).

Comment: I count 5 constructors, and 5 destructors.  (On my machine, with `-O3`, I have 4 and 4.)  I'm not sure why you think there is an "additional" destructor call.

Comment: I have made one that labels the objects with an ID so it is obvious what is being constructed/destructed and it is more clear: https://godbolt.org/z/jfd9fj9eo   Interestingly, gcc 11 only makes 4 objects (which are all destructed) - have a look at: https://godbolt.org/z/aTa6hGE44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what am I missing here?

The destruction of `T2`.

There are 3+2 constructors called, there must be 3+2 destructors called too!

Comment: Damn, I can't believe I missed this. Thanks!